# List inside datatable [Laravel] [Query builder]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to add a datatable in my applicaction which will look like this:

[image: datatable example]

It's a datatable that shows all the trainers of a given manager_id.

My problem is that I don't know how to manage to create an unordered list in the column **Gymnasts** which should show all the gymnasts that have been assigned to the trainer

My MySQL table users has the following fields:

- id (PK)
- name
- email
- email_verified_at
- type
- manager_id
- trainer_id
- firstName
- lastName

I have now this in my controller so I can get a complete list of the trainers and their gymnasts asigned but I want to concat all the gymnasts in a list to be able to show it

```
$user = Auth::user();

        if ($user['type'] == "Manager"){
            $gymnasts = DB::table('users as trainer')
                ->leftJoin('users as gymnast', 'gymnast.trainer_id', '=', 'trainer.id')
                ->select('trainer.id', 'trainer.name', 'trainer.firstName', 'trainer.lastName','gymnast.firstName as gymnastName' ,'gymnast.lastName as gymnastSurname','trainer.email_verified_at')
                ->where('gymnast.manager_id', $user['id'])
                ->where('gymnast.type', 'Trainer')
                ->get();

            return view('layouts.users.indexTrainers',['type' => $user['type'],'gymnasts' => $gymnasts]);

        }else{
            return back()
                ->withErrors(['error' => 'You are not allowed to access this layout.']);
        }
```

The view code will be something similar to this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($trainer as $key => $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$data->firstName}} {{$data->lastName}}</td>
            <td>
                @if($u->gymnasts)
                    @foreach($u->gymnast as $g)
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{$g->name}} {{$g->surname}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    @endforeach
                @else
                    <i>No gymnast assigned yet.</i>
                @endempty
            </td>
            <td>
                 @isset($data->email_verified_at)
                     <span class="badge badge-success">Activated</span></td>
                 @else
                     <span class="badge badge-danger">Inactive</span>
                 @endempty
             <td>
                 @isset($data->email_verified_at)
                     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> View</button>
                 @else
                     <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i> Resend email</button>
                 @endempty
                 <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
     @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I expect to get a field with

```
<ul><li>Name1 Surname1</li><li>Name2 Surname2</li></ul>
```

so I can inject it in the cell.

Thanks in advance for the help.

***Aditional note:***

- One **manager** can manage N users (gymnasts or trainers)
- One **trainer** can train N gymnasts
- One **trainer** can be managed by only one manager
- One **gymnast** can be trained by only one trainer
- One **gymnast** can be managed by only one manager

Comment: create a relationship to the gymnast and call the with method when fetching records as in eager loading data

Comment: Hi @spartyboy, thanks for you answer. Can you explain it with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one table 'users' with different role then you need to create a self relatioship this will help you find trainers for every user try this:

```
  function trainers(){
                return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id','trainer_id');
            }

        function manager(){
            return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id','manager_id');
        }
```

and in blade do something like this

```
@foreach($users as $u)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{$u->name}} <br/>

                            @if($u->trainers)

                                @foreach($u->trainers as $t)
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>{{$t->name}}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Controller code may be:

```
User::query()->with('trainers')
                ->whereNotIn('user.type', ,['Trainer','Manager'])
                  ->where('user.manager_id', manager_id)
                  ->get()
```

Comment: thanks for your asnwer. I understand that the first box functions should be added in the Model to define the relationship but, how to get them in the Controller to send it to the view? Thanks again.

Comment: I need trainer name and surname + list of all gymnasts assigned (name+surname) + trainer status

Comment: You can add custom attributes in your model:

 protected $appends = array('sur_name');

    public function getSurNameAttribute()
    {
    return $this->first_name + '' + $this->last_name;
    }

and then in your blade you directly get sur name like this $u->surName

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem like this:

**Controller**

```
$user = Auth::user();

$trainers = DB::table('users as trainer')
    ->leftJoin('users as gymnast', 'gymnast.trainer_id', '=', 'trainer.id')
    ->select('trainer.id', 'trainer.firstName', 'trainer.lastName',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(gymnast.firstName," ",gymnast.lastName)) AS gymnastList'),'trainer.email_verified_at')
    ->where('gymnast.manager_id', $user['id'])
    ->where('trainer.type', "Trainer")
    ->where('gymnast.type', "Gymnast")
    ->groupBy('trainer.id')
    ->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach($trainers as $key => $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$data->firstName}} {{$data->lastName}}</td>
        <td>
            @isset($data->gymnastList)
                {!! App\User::listGymnasts($data->gymnastList) !!}
            @else
                <i>No gymnasts assigned yet.</i>
            @endempty
         </td>
         <td>
             @isset($data->email_verified_at)
                 <span class="badge badge-success">Active</span>
             @else
                 <span class="badge badge-danger">Inactive</span>
             @endempty
          </td>
          <td>
              @isset($data->email_verified_at)
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> View</button>
              @else
                  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i> Resend email</button>
              @endempty
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button>
          </td>
       </tr>
 @endforeach
```

**Model**

```
public static function listGymnasts($gymnastList){
        $gymnasts = explode(',', $gymnastList);
        $text = "<ul>";
        foreach($gymnasts as $gymnast){
            $text = $text."<li>".$gymnast."</li>";
        }
        $text = $text.'</ul>';

        return $text;
    }
```

The only problem I've found is when the trainer has no gymnasts assigned. In that case, the datatable don't show this trainer row. When I found the solution for that I will update my answer.